# Oracle query for Convert from Julian value to Date with Time

Tags: oracle, timestamp, julian-date

I have to convert from Julian value to Regular Date with time.

```
Select to_char(to_date(2455198, 'J'), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss') from dual;
```

This query is working and the result is `01-01-2010 12:00:00`

```
Select to_char(to_date(2455197.75001, 'J'), 'DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss') from dual;
```

This above query is not working and got this error:

> ORA:01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Julian value: `2455197.75001` and equivalent date value is: `1-January-2010 06:00:01`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Chris said, J needs an integer so you can use `floor` or `trunc` to get that, and use the fractional part as a number of partial days (and add another half a day, as @Chris noted in a comment, to account for Julian days [starting at noon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day)):

```
Select to_char(
    to_date(floor(2455197.75001), 'J')
      + mod(2455197.75001, 1)
      + 0.5,
  'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:mi:ss')
from dual;
```

which gets:

```
01-01-2010 06:00:01
```

Note that I changed `HH` to `HH24`, and the second `mm` to `mi` for minutes.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b2db0e57d4f8cf920266f3f4dc8905cc)

Comment: Julian days start at noon, you need to add another half-day (12 hours) to the date after the Julian conversion

Comment: Ah, I did not know that, thank you! Strange that Oracle doesn't set the time portion to midday then.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use fractions with Julian values. As the [docs state](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-EAB212CF-C525-4ED8-9D3F-C76D08EEBC7A):

> Julian day; the number of days since January 1, 4712 BC. **Number
> specified with J must be integers.**